# child_process exits with code null

Tags: node.js

I am running my node server in centos6.X, and forking a child process.

```
var cp = require('child_process');
child = cp.fork(__dirname+'/worker');
child.on('exit', function (code, signal) {
            console.log('Child exited with code = ' +code+'  signal = '+signal);
 });
```

but after few seconds I get this error

> Child exited with code = null  signal = SIGKILL

I am now clueless  how to get rid of this, there is no more trace, as to what is happening.

**more clarification**

I have put console.logs in worker and they are getting printed. the worker is now waiting for message from main server. but exits after waiting for few seconds. I also run the worker js independently with node command and there it does not exit.

The same code works fine on my local OSX laptop. but on cloud centos6.X I am facing this issue.

Comment: I'm not very familiar with the `.fork` nodejs API but I think it takes in a module, which I think would typically be a `.js` file that has something like `module.export`? How does your `worker` file look like? Or maybe you may have missed the `.js` bit?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

There are two ways a child process can exit: voluntarily, in which case an exit code will be returned, or involuntarily, through a signal.

From the arguments of the `exit` handler, the first reflects the exit code, and the second the signal. One of these will contain a value, the other one will be `null`. As explained in [the documentation](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_event_exit):

> If the process exited, `code` is the final exit code of the process, otherwise `null`. If the process terminated due to receipt of a signal, `signal` is the string name of the signal, otherwise `null`. One of the two will always be non-null.

If your child process receives a `SIGKILL`, and you're not the one that (explicitly) sent that signal, there's a good chance that the child process got killed by the Linux [OOM killer](https://linux-mm.org/OOM_Killer), which kills processes in case the system is strapped for memory ("OOM" means *"Out Of Memory"*).

So make sure that your system has enough RAM, enough swap, and/or that your process doesn't take up too much memory (if possible).

Comment: I just tried to add swap memory and it worked. thanks.

Answer (score 5):

In my case, the process run by `exec` was printing too much output and the **maxBuffer** was reached (see [maxBuffer](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_processexeccommand-options-callback) option of `exec`), which caused NodeJS to detach from the child process with a `null` exit code, while the child process kept running in the background until it finished successfully.

If this is your case as well, the solution is to simply increase the `maxBuffer` option, which is 1MB by default (as of writing this).

Thanks to [Sathish](https://sathishsuresh.medium.com/) for [pointing this out](https://sathishsuresh.medium.com/node-js-child-process-exec-exit-code-null-d29838b9f309).