# node.js child_process returns code = null when running certain processes

Tags: node.js, heroku, child-process

I am running into an issue with spawning a child_process in my prod environment. Everything works fine in my dev environment (windows), but when I push to production (Heroku) some of the child_processes fail and return code = null. Below is my code:

```
router.get('/element/chart/:id', ensureAuthenticated, (req,res) => {
    var current_data_page_id = req.params.id
    const path = require('path')
    const {spawn} = require('child_process')
    let runScript;
    
    runScript = (current_data_page_id) => {
        switch(current_data_page_id) {
            case "100":
                return spawn('python', ["-u", path.join(process.cwd(),'/python/python_func_1.py')]); 
            break;
            case "101":
                return spawn('python', ["-u", path.join(process.cwd(),'/python/python_func_2.py')]);
            break;
            case "102":
                return spawn('python', ["-u", path.join(process.cwd(),'/python/python_func_3.py')]);
            break;
            case "103":
                return spawn('python', ["-u", path.join(process.cwd(),'/python/python_func_4.py')]);
            break;
            case "200":
                return spawn('python', ["-u", path.join(process.cwd(),'/python/python_func_5.py')]);
            break;
            case "201": 
                return spawn('python', ["-u", path.join(process.cwd(),'/python/python_func_6.py')]);
            break;
            default:
                console.log("Data page ID does not match current options") 
        };
    };
    
    const subprocess = runScript(current_data_page_id)
    // print output of script
    subprocess.stdout.on('data', (data) => {
        console.log("HERE I AM")
        var dataToSend = data.toString();
        res.write(dataToSend);
    });
    
    //NEW Dx CODE
    subprocess.on('error', (err) => {
        console.log(`Spawn error: ${err}`)
    });

    subprocess.stderr.on('data', (data) => {
        console.log(`error:${data}`);
        return;
    });
    subprocess.stderr.on('close', () => {
        console.log("Closed");
        return;
    });
    subprocess.on('close', (code) => {
        if (code !== 0) {
            console.log(`grep process exited with code ${code}`);
        }
        res.end(); 
    });

});
```

For example in production the case=100's all work, but the case=200's fail. In development all work fine.

All I see in the console is "Closed" and "grep process exited with code null". The two failing python functions share a decent bit of code. I'm thinking that perhaps I am exceeding memory allotment   in the production environment? Although I don't have any stack trace / error which specifically indicates that.

Comment: where is your `subprocess.on('error", evt => ... )` handler, for catching spawn errors (rather than execution errors)?

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans I added an addtnl event handler to the code in the question - not sure if my syntax is correct to capture potential range of relevant events (new to node). Still no additional console activity other than "Closed" and "grep process...code null"

Comment: You might need to turn this into a [mcve], although on a different note: why are you running python scripts on demand, instead of having a python job handler running in parallel that you can ask runs from via, say, REST calls?

Comment: Is there a way to log why the OS sent a signal to end my child_process, even if it is not covered by the "error" event? Also [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39159312/child-process-exits-with-code-null) suggests OOM_killer is a common culprit for this type of behavior. Is there a way to provision more memory for the child process in spawn to test this?

Comment: Hence my question: why are you using child processes here, instead of having a python service running that you can ask to do work using REST calls (e.g. have python do the python things, have node do the node things, and have node ask python for data via same-machine HTTP calls?)

Comment: Really to minimize complexity. I am not experienced with Django/RESTful API development/OAuth/JWT API authentication. This will likely be a very low volume web service. If it can be solved with child processes that would be preferred vs developing secure API in unfamiliar framework.

Comment: why would you need any of that if you're running it inaccessibly to the rest of the world on the same machine so that only your node process can talk to it? Just write the thinnest of veneer that listens for local GET requests on a closed-to-the-world port, and runs the python function(s) you're currently running with -y with the dumbest invocations (like "GET /100", akin to what you're doing already), then returns the data. No DRF, no "API", no OAuth, no JWT: you're not writing a second web server.

Comment: Gotcha - do you know of any good docs/examples showing potential request structure for same-machine HTTP calls?

Comment: There's nothing special about them, really. As long as something runs a local server that accepts GET requests, the process is identical to any other fetch request. In Node, you'd run a quick and easy web server (which you wouldn't have to do in this case) with [expressjs](https://expressjs.com/) and make requests with [node-fetch](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-fetch), in Python you'd run a quick and easy web server with [flask](https://palletsprojects.com/p/flask/) and make requests (which you wouldn't have to do in this case) using the built-in `requests`.